# Non-measurable sets on groups from translation invariance

Tags: gr.group-theory, measure-theory, topological-groups

The most well-known construction of a non-measurable set is the Vitali set. The idea behind Vitali sets is to split up the space (such as $[0,1]$) into equal-sized copies (guaranteed by translation invariance), by looking at something like $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. This same idea is used in ["Visualizing a Nonmeasurable Set"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219308?seq=4#metadata_info_tab_contents) to construct non-measurable sets on the torus.

Another construction I know about is on the probability space of infinitely many coin tosses $\{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N}$. In this case, instead of modding out by $\mathbb{Q}$, you can mod out by "switching the outcome of finitely many coins". This approach is taken in [these probability lecture notes](http://tamuz.caltech.edu/teaching/ma144a/lectures.pdf).

All of these constructions seem closely related: each time, we have a way to decompose our set into "translation-invariant" copies. **My question is how these sorts of constructions of non-measurable sets generalize.** In the  [Wikipedia article on Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) I read:

> Unless $G$ is a discrete group, it is impossible to define a countably additive left-invariant regular measure on all subsets of $G$, assuming the axiom of choice, according to the theory of non-measurable sets.

This seems very close to an answer to my question, but the Wikipedia article doesn't elaborate here. So, how does the construction of non-measurable sets on a non-discrete group $G$ work? Is the general intuition similar to the examples I've described here? What happens for discrete groups (could this be related to amenable groups, which I know you can put measures on)?

Comment: It's not really a construction, and it's hard to call some specific set "the" Vitali set.

Comment: @YCor This is a fair point. I suppose my language there was chosen more for brevity than precision. By "the" I was intending to convey "the most well-known kind of Vitali set". Your objection to the word "construction" is interesting, do you just mean that it's not morally a construction since it depends on AC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof for the reals can be generalized to any non-discrete locally compact group $G$. We let $K \subset G$ be any compact set with positive Haar measure $\lambda(K) > 0$ (e.g., $K = [0, 1]$ when $G = \mathbb R$), and we let $\Lambda < G$ be any subgroup such that $\Lambda \cap KK^{-1}$ is countably infinite (e.g., $\Lambda = \mathbb Q$ when $G = \mathbb R$). We define an equivalence relation on $G$ by the $\Lambda$-orbits coming from left multiplication and we let $V \subset K$ be a set containing exactly one representative of each equivalence class that intersects non-trivially with $\Lambda K$.

We then have $K \subset (\Lambda \cap K K^{-1}) V \subset K K^{-1} K$. The first inclusion here follows from the fact that if $k \in K$, then we may find $t \in \Lambda$ such that $tk \in V \subset K$. It then follows that $t = (tk) k^{-1} \in K K^{-1}$ and hence $k \in (\Lambda \cap K K^{-1})V$.

If we were able to extend the Haar measure to a countably additive left-invariant measure defined on all subsets of $G$, then we would have $\lambda(( \Lambda \cap K K^{-1} ) V) = \sum_{t \in \Lambda \cap K K^{-1}} \lambda(V) \in \{ 0, \infty \}$, but this would then contradict the inequalities
$$
0 < \lambda(K) \leq \lambda( ( \Lambda \cap K K^{-1} ) V ) \leq \lambda(K K^{-1} K) < \infty.
$$

Comment: How often does such a pair $(K, \Lambda)$ exist?

Comment: Such pairs exist for all non-discrete locally compact groups. Haar measure is always finite on compact sets, and since Haar measure is inner-regular a set $K$ with the properties above exists. Since $G$ is not discrete the set $K$ must be infinite and you can take $\Lambda$ to be any subgroup generated by a countably infinite subset of $K K^{-1}$.

Comment: Why does $\Lambda$ generated by a countable subset of $K K^{-1}$ intersect $K K^{-1}$ only countably often?

Comment: @LSpice because a countable subset generates a countable subgroup (in every group).

Comment: @YCor, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381302/non-measurable-sets-on-groups-from-translation-invariance/381916#comment970982_381916).  I was thinking of topological generation and so forgot that this was just a bare not-necessarily-closed group.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer (does not use translation invariance)

Another non-measurable set, which may generalize more easily, is the [Bernstein set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set) ... That is, a set $E$ such that for every uncountable closed set A, we have $A \cap E \ne \varnothing$ and $A \setminus E \ne \varnothing$ .

[With AC] we can prove that any uncountable Polish space admits a Bernstein set (indeed, $\mathfrak c$ disjoint Bernstein sets).
If  $\mu$ is any atomless Borel measure on an uncountable Polish space,
then a Bernstein set is not $\mu$-measurable.

Comment: Isn't "measurable" relative to a $\sigma$-algebra rather than a measure? which $\sigma$-algebra do you mean? the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to every $\sigma$-finite (finite?) Borel measure?

Comment: Here we use measurable for a measure.  (For example, Lebesuge measurable.) I added some info.

Comment: What does "measurable for a measure" mean, if not belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra on which the measure is defined?  Since you refer to a Borel measure, does that mean that measurability is with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @LSpice i guess the answer is in my comment, although Gerald Elgar didn't clearly confirm.

Comment: $\mu$-measurable in the sense of Caratheodory.  When $\mu$ is a sigma-finite Borel measure this could mean the completion of the Borel sets for $\mu$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar This "non-answer" is still very useful since I hadn't heard of examples which don't appeal to some sort of translation invariance. Classic XY problem. I'm still hoping someone will get closer to answering the original question about translation invariance but thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

For any infinite group $G$ we can easily construct a Vitali subset $V$ of $G$. Indeed, pick an arbitrary countable infinite subgroup $H$ of $G$ and let $V$ be a subset of $G$ which intersects each right coset $Hg$ of $H$ is exactly one element. Then $G$ is a disjoint union of a countable infinite family $\{hV:h\in H\}$ consisting of left translation copies of the set $V$. Let $\mu$ be any countably additive left-invariant probability measure on $G$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $H$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$. If $\mu(H)=0$ then $\mu(G)=0$, a contradiction. If $\mu(H)>0$ then $\mu(G)$ is infinite, a contradiction.

Remark that the above construction of $V$ works even for amenable groups, because a left-invariant probability measure required by amenability is required to be *finitely*-additive.

Also remark that the main result of the paper [BGR] easily implies that if $G$ is a meager Hausdorff (para)topological group then the set $V$ can be constructed to be nowhere dense in $G$.

*References*

[BGR] Taras Banakh, Igor Guran, Alex Ravsky, *[Characterizing meager paratopological groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2225)*, Applied general topology **12**:1 (2011) 27–33.

Comment: Why does $G$ support a countably additive left-invariant probability measure?

Comment: @LSpice I do not claim that $G$ supports such measure. But if $G$ supports such measure  $\mu$ then $H$ is not measurable with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: What is known about for which $G$ we can get such a countably additive left-invariant probability measure?

Comment: @aras The characterization of such $G$ depends on which its subsets are required to be measurable. My answer implies that all subsets of $G$ are measurable iff $G$ is finite. If $G$ is countably infinite then a one-point  subset $\{x\}$ of $G$ cannot be measurable, because each of assumptions $\mu(\{x\})=0$ and  $\mu(\{x\})>0$ easily implies a contradiction.

Comment: But if $G$ is uncountable then we can define a measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ consisting of all subsets $A$ of $G$ such that either $A$ or $G\setminus A$ is countable, and putting $\mu(G)=0$ in the first case and $\mu(G)=1$, in the second.

Comment: ah, i see you too were suspended by the maths se mods/admins. https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71850/alex-ravsky anyhoo thanks for editing the post on which i set a bounty https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2057393/revisions

Comment: @Alexravsky It is proved that $H$ is not measurable; but $V$ must be proved unmeasurable. See the last paragraph of the proof

Comment: @alexravsky in fact you have proved that every right transversal of every countably infinite subgroup of a group is not measurable.